# Setting Y labels to start from 0 instead of 20%

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Image that I am getting with this code]

Hi, I am trying to plot the usage pattern for two years using a bar chart. Below is the code :

```
for yr in years:
    x = ["Notes", "BookMarks", "Revision", "Glossary", "SolvedQuestion"]
    y = [NotesUsage[yr], BookmarkUsage[yr], RevisionUsage[yr],GlossaryUsage[yr],SolvedQuestion[yr]]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax.bar(x, y)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())
    ax.set_ylim(ymin = 0.00)
    ax.set_xlabel("Additional Revision Tools")
    ax.set_ylabel("Percent Users")
    ax.set_title("Additional Study Tools Usage Pattern - Year {}, Class - {}".format(yr, Class))
    fig.savefig(destination+"UsagePattern"+Class+"-"+str(yr)+".png")
    fig.clear()
```

I want the Y axis to start at 0.00%, however, it is starting at 18%. To correct it, I have also specified the `ax.set_ylim(0)` - but it doesn't seem to work. 
Please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: No its not. The numbers there are absolute and here its in percent,

Comment: Calling `PercentFormatter` has no effect on the logic here, the solution is the same.

Comment: Your are plotting categorical data instead of numeric ones. `ax.set_ylim(0)` works fine. The axis in indeed limited to 0. And the label of the tick at 0 is `"18.07%"`.

I suppose you want to to plot numbers instead of categories. This means that you need to use numbers as input. You may then use `PercentFormatter` in addition if needed.